# Merging SQS messages

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-iam

Is there an easy way to redirect all messages from many queues into a single "catch-all" queue and to alter the message by adding the source queue name as an attribute called "source"?

The reason I need more queues (instead of a single one) is: I want to use IAM policies for regulating users' access to individual sources.

***EDIT:***

What I need to build is quite simple:

1. Users indicate that a file stored in S3 should be processed by our software

   - For this notification, they can use any AWS service, it can be a Lambda function, API, SQS, SNS. Whatever works.
   - As a limitation, I cannot restrict users from uploading files or to impose naming conventions.
   - IAM user running our software has access to user's content
2. After notification, a process will update the file content and will move the result into the designated location

   - The destination location depends on the content or it can be provided by user. Any approach will work.

The issues is that I need to make sure users are sending data to the locations they are allowed to. I'd like to only use IAM policies and to avoid having a "rights" database.

What I thought is to have a SQS for each destination location and to grant users access to the appropriate list of SQS. If they post a request on a queue they have access to, then the main process can safely fulfill the request.
The drawback is that the main process has to listen to many SQS and that we need to update it whenever we alter the configuration of the destination locations.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you can provide more information about your goal, we might be able to suggest an alternative method. Feel free to Edit your question to add more details.

Comment: Thanks; I added more details.

Comment: Every time you receive a message from SQS, it has a [`SenderId` attribute](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ReceiveMessage.html) that you can receive, if you ask... which identifies the sender of the message by IAM user or role.  Would that not be usable for determining the validity of each request?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Simple Queue Service (SQS) itself is a very simple (hence the name). You can create a queue, send a message to a queue, retrieve a message from a queue, delete the queue an not much else.

Anything else you'd like to do needs to be done by your own application that sends/receives messages to/from a queue.

You **cannot** instruct SQS to redirect messages nor modify the content of messages.

If you wish to have **multiple consumers of messages**, a common practice is to initially send the message to Amazon Simple Notification Service (SNS) and it can forward the message to multiple queues. Users can then retrieve messages fro their own queue without impacting other users' queues.

Comment: It's the other way around: I'd like to have multiple producers and a single consumer.